# How would I filter through data that was fetched by a server component? - NextJS 13 AppDir

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I've been trying to figure out how to implement a search bar that filters through data that has been fetched by a server component using NextJS 13 and AppDir, but nothing has been working. I feel like I'm missing something though.

Most guides that explain search bar functionality tell you to use states, etc. However, this can only be used client side, not server side. I had implemented one of these, and tried to pass the value to the server side function, but no success.

I had the idea of using search params, but, these again can only be accessed by the client side. At this point I'm wondering what can server side functions even access?

I could put the fetch request on the client side and this would all probably work, but, correct me if I'm wrong, isn't that incredibly unsecure? I have bearer tokens, etc, used for authentication that the client side would then be accessing.

Maybe I'm just missing the point (I probably am), but it would be greatly appreciated if someone could explain how implementing a search bar that filters through server-side fetched data would work.

Answer (score 1):

`useSearchParams` is client side only, but you can access search parameters from your Page file as well.

```
export default function Page({
  params,
  searchParams,
}: {
  params: { slug: string }
  searchParams: { [key: string]: string | string[] | undefined }
}) {
  return <h1>My Page</h1>
}
```

https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/file-conventions/page#searchparams-optional